# Browser Hopper Window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-explorer, file-transfer, google-chrome-extensions

The idea is to use a small dedicated File Explorer window set to a certain folder with the navigation pane removed, and use this as quick triage to the browser. My current aim is to remove all but the first column in File Explorer 'Content' view, having only one column without date and size. Such a hopper would be useful for 'drag & drop' actions paired with an 'always on top' hotkey.

Alternately, a sidebar chrome extension dynamically containing the contents of chosen folder(s). Are there any extensions that currently allow local file manipulation?

Comment: I was going to suggest a combination of AHK and RainMeter, but I think given the usage of the two (or even just AHK alone), you can eliminate the need for the File Explorer window entirely.

Comment: what gui interface if not file explorer?

Comment: AHK and/or RainMeter.  For persistance/stay-on-top as well as aesthetics, the latter works nicely in tandem with AHK, but AHK itself has GUI capabilities (I've not used it for those features myself, but I've seen it in some of the showcased scripts).